# adding line break

Tags: c#, line-breaks

I have a problem with adding line break in a string. I have tried using "\r\n", and Environment.NewLine also does not work.

```
FirmNames = "";

foreach (var item in FirmNameList)
{
    if (FirmNames != "")
    {
       FirmNames += ", " + LineBreak;  -- I want a line break here after the comma ","
    }

    FirmNames += item;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you get when you `Console.WriteLine(FirmNames)` after the loop?

Comment: What are you outputting the resulting string to? A control? The console?  Some controls don't support line breaks or have properties you have to set to allow line breaks.

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder`, as they are much more efficient than appending `string`s together

Answer (score 62):

The correct answer is to use `Environment.NewLine`, as you've noted.  It is environment specific and provides clarity over "\r\n" (but in reality makes no difference).

```
foreach (var item in FirmNameList) 
{
    if (FirmNames != "")
    {
        FirmNames += ", " + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    FirmNames += item; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try.

```
        FirmNames = String.Join(", \n", FirmNameList);
```

Answer (score 6):

## **C# 6+**

In addition, since c#6 you can also use a ***static using statement for System.Environment***.

So instead of ***Environment.NewLine***, you can just write ***NewLine***.

Concise and much easier on the eye, particularly when there are multiple instances ...

```
using static System.Environment;
   
...

foreach (var item in FirmNameList)
{
    if (FirmNames != "")
    {
       FirmNames += ", " + NewLine;
    }
    FirmNames += item;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
foreach (var item in FirmNameList){
    if (FirmNames != "")
    {
        FirmNames += ",\r\n"
    }

    FirmNames += item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `\n` when concatenating strings, as in this example:

```
var name = "Raihan";
var ID = "1234";
Console.WriteLine(name + "\n" + ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

### `\n` in c3 working correctly

using System;
namespace `testing2`

```
public class Test { 
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        String s = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + s + "\n" + "Thank You");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, in my case I use several because some don't work on the platform I need, you can try the following:

```
Environment.NewLine //--> recommendable
\n
\r
\n\r
\r\n
```

Answer (score -1):

3 WAYS TO INSERT A NEW LINE IN C#
1:

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a line");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("This is another line");
```

2:

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a line.\nThis is another line.");
```

3:

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a line." + Environment.NewLine + "This is another line.");
```

Comment: https://www.sitereq.com/post/6-ways-to-insert-new-line-in-c-and-aspnet

Answer (score -6):

```
string[] abcd = obj.show(); 

Response.Write(string.join("</br>", abcd));
```