# make line break in string array output in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview

how to make line break between words in this following code ? i want to show each output have line break like this so that it can be seen properly. this is my code and output that i want :

```
try
{
    //DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)ViewState["Information"];
    DataTable dtDistinctRecords = dtTemp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "prod_line");
    DataTable dtStudentName = dtTemp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "request_date");
    DataTable a = new DataTable();

    DataTable dtStudent = new DataTable();

    dtStudent.Columns.Add("request_date");
    foreach (DataRow rows in dtDistinctRecords.Rows)
    {
        dtStudent.Columns.Add(rows["prod_line"].ToString());
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dtStudentName.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtStudent.NewRow();
        dr["request_date"] = row["request_date"];
        DataView dv = new DataView(dtTemp);
        dv.RowFilter = "request_date='" + row["request_date"] + "'";
        DataTable dtStudentdtl = dv.ToTable();

        for (int i = 0; i < dtStudentdtl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string colValue = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["jo_no"].ToString();
            string colValue2 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["qty"].ToString();
            string colValue3 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["need_by_date"].ToString();
            string colValue4 = dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["process_id"].ToString();
            dr[dtStudentdtl.Rows[i]["prod_line"].ToString()] = "Job Order: " + colValue + "  Quantity: " + colValue2 + "  Need by Date: " + colValue3 + "  Status: " + colValue4;
            var joinedWords = string.Join(" ", dtStudent);                            
        }

        dtStudent.Rows.InsertAt(dr, dtStudent.Rows.Count);
    }

    GridView1.CellPadding = 10;
    GridView1.DataSource = dtStudent;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView_Row_Merger(GridView1);

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

[link output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzNcn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your for loop to make a sample code snippet:

```
   string colValue = "job order: 124"+System.Environment.NewLine+System.Environment.NewLine;
            string colValue2 = "Quantity: 100" + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine;
            string colValue3 = "Need by Date:2/5/2017" + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine;
            string colValue4 = "Status: Pending"+System.Environment.NewLine;
            string finalString = colValue + colValue2 + colValue3 + colValue4;
```

and in front end i am getting following output:

[image]

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: i use your format and make some changes in my code. thank you it works !

Comment: Welcome, nice to hear :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first result from google for you, [adding line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755204/adding-line-break),
or for short `\r\n`